# Domain, hosting, and email

Tags: domain-name-system

This may not be the site for this question

I have a domain name I registered with 1and1. I am using squarespace to host my website, pointing to that domain, and I just signed up for office365, and want to use that for email.

Squarespace provided me with an IP address to set as the A record. I added this on my 1and1 admin console, and was able to access my webpage. Office 365 provided me with two name servers, for my email, and told me this would not change my A record mapping. As soon as I entered the name server information, I was no longer able to bring up my web page at squarespace.

I do not know much about DNS or hosting, so I am not sure if what I want to do is even possible. Though I imagine it would be.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would Office 365 provide you with _nameservers_? Just exactly what directions were you trying to use?

Comment: @MichaelHampton When I log in to O365, on the admin page, there is an option for configuring your domain to work with O365. There are 5 steps, where you verify you own the domain, the users, and then it provides you with name server settings to add to my DNS console. Here is one of the name servers it gave me: `ns1.bdm.microsoftonline.com`

Comment: Oh OK, so you want Office 365 to manage your DNS for you. In that case, you need to migrate your A records and other records yourself.

Comment: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-smallbusinesses/hh335298.aspx

Comment: I don't know if that is what I want. Is it possible I don't need to do anything with my DNS in order for my O365 email to work? I intend to keep the domain registered with 1and1. I guess I am asking how to configure both the website AND the email through the 1and1 DNS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You could do it that way, but it's a lot more work, especially if you ever intend to use other O365 services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so it looks like microsoft does provide authoritative name servers for office 365... and it sounds like you already moved your authoritative name servers over to MS.  once you did that, the existing A record for squarespace ceased to exist, as it was not on MS NS's.   you have to add that A record to your new authoritative nameservers with microsoft.

http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-smallbusinesses/hh416759.aspx
http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-smallbusinesses/jj655390.aspx

the above links should explain the difference between having 1and1 host your dns, and adding the necessary records to make O365 work for your domain, as opposed to having microsoft host your auth ns's.

if you keep microsoft as your authoritative name servers, it is not clear to me that they will let you add an A record to a third party (ie. squarespace IP)

i would probably advise to revert to using 1and1 NS's, and manually add the dns records needed for O365, as per articles above.

Comment: I think I understand. It was not my intent to use MSFT as authoritative. I just added those nameservers because I thought it was what I needed to do. Those two links, in addition to what @Michael Hampton provided, look like they are what I need. Thank you. It at least answers my question. Otherwise I would have been adding the A record then adding the MSFT NS's back and forth for days. Without a clue as to what the hell was wrong. EDIT: I am not worthy enough to upvote anything.